# Op-Amp Input Common Voltage Range for specific gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

This is the circuit I am working on.

[image: circuit]

I am using this instrumental amplifier AD623 with a gain of 100 using a 1k resistor between pin 1 and 8.

(https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf)

Based on this, my input voltage can swing from -0.05v to 0.05v.
When input voltage is 0.05v the simulation works without problems as I post on the image.
The problem I am having is that when input voltage is -0.05v I get error on simulation and I think is because I exceed specs of the input common voltage of the ic.

I need to understand how can I get correct output voltage based on the input voltage I mention.

(If input voltage is -0.05v output can be any value <5v without problem in this circuit design)

Comment: What error, specifically? By the way, your PC's operating system has a screenshot function, so that you don't have to take photos of your screen like it was 1978...

Comment: By the way, you call your differential input voltage "input voltage", right? Well, if you amplify 0.05 V by 100, what voltage do you get? What is the maximum voltage a device can produce with your supply voltage?

Comment: Sorry I can not understand correctly. Maybe you can explain me again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gain is set to 101, so you're expecting an output voltage of about 5V. If you look at the datasheet:

[image]

The output can only approach 5V for a very narrow range of common mode voltage.

If you give it a -5V rail it will be able to handle a much wider range of inputs for output near the positive rail, as shown in Fig. 32 & 33.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Spehro!. Maybe you can help me understanding Figure 33. What voltage input I have to supply to get 5v output.

Comment: If you have +/-5V supply voltages, then a +50mV difference will result in ~5V out for any common mode voltage between about -3V and almost +2V. +/-5V is the outer "ring" (the diagram is not all that clear on that point).

Comment: Excelllent Response!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: May I suggest the https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond ? This INA is supported and it is a very useful tool to experiment on the limitation imposed by the internal and external nodes and voltage rails.

Comment: @vangelo That's a nice tool and eliminates a lot of guesswork, especially for non-standard voltage rails.  OP: You could have found this from the AD product page under "Tools & Simulations"